# Select data having all values in an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

here's my problem:
I've got a table `idtypedata` made out of two columns:

- `IDdata`
- `IDtype`

Both of them aren't unique.

I want to output a table displaying `IDdata` for each time all occurrences  a given list have been found in `IDtype` for the same `IDdata`.

As an example:

with the list (12,5)

```
IDdata    IDtype
 221        12
 221        5
 157        12
 187        5
```

The query should only return the `IDdata` when `IDtype` met all the list parameters:

```
IDdata
 221
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also known as relational division:

```
select iddata
from idtypedata
where idtype in (12,5)
group by iddata
having count(distinct idtype) = 2;
```

However this would also return `iddata` values that have other idtypes as well (e.g. 12,5,6).

To make the condition for the having clause independent of the actual number of IDs to check, I would move the list of IDs into a CTE:

```
with idlist (id) as (
  values (12), (5)
)
select iddata
from idtypedata
where idtype in (select id from idlist)
group by iddata
having count(distinct idtype) = (select count(*) from idlist);
```

To get those that have **exactly** those two elements, you can use an array to compare to:

```
with idlist (id) as (
  values (12), (5)
)
select iddata
from idtypedata
where idtype in (select id from idlist)
group by iddata
having array_agg(idtype order by idtype) = (select array_agg(id order by id) from idlist);
```

The `order by` in the `array_agg()` is important because the array `{12,5}` is not the same as `{5,12}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know about that one

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how would you go about using this for multiple values? Dynamic SQL & counting the separators in your IN clause +1 to get the count value?

Answer (score 1):

Use group by and having. Below query give you output for all occurrences of idtype.

```
            select distinct iddata
            from idtypedata
            group by iddata
            having count(distinct idtype) > 1
```

please let us know if u have any concerns.